# Script for Partial rendering using Response.Redirect Not working in chrome and mozilla

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dom, response.write

Below is my code......

```
    Response.Write("<Table style='border:1px solid #0B5226;background-color: white;' runat='server' width = '100%'> <Tr style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; vertical-align:middle; text-align:left;'><Td width='15%'> <img src='../Images_v4/Common/Progress.gif' /></Td><Td width='80%' style='text-align: left;word-break: break-all;'><Div>In</Div></Td></Table>");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");

    Response.Write("var nr = document.all.length;");
    Response.Write("for(i=0;i<nr;i++)");
    Response.Write("{");

    Response.Write("if(document.all(i).tagName == 'IMG' && document.all(i).nameProp == 'Progress.gif')");
    Response.Write("{");
    Response.Write("document.all(i).src = '../Images_v4/Common/Success.png';");
    Response.Write("}");

    Response.Write("if(document.all(i).tagName == 'DIV' && document.all(i).innerHTML == 'In Progress...')");
    Response.Write("{");
    Response.Write("document.all(i).innerHTML = 'Processed Successful';");
    Response.Write("}");



    Response.Write("}");
    Response.Write("</script>");

    Response.Flush();
```

The above code shows status message from an aspx page by writing response and after some time when a particular things has completed working it changes the status image from progress to success.
The above code works fine in IE since the ***document.all(i).nameProp*** seems to work in IE.But this thing does'nt work in other browser such as chrome and mozilla.Is there any alternative to ***document.all(i).nameProp*** which works in all browsers.Or any other method of achieving this.
I'm using c# web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`. `document.all` is for old IE (IE5) only.

nameProp is also IE only, but a similar can be easily achieved by a simple regex function:

For absolute compatibility:

```
function getFileName(path) {
    return path.match(/[-_\w]+[.][\w]+$/i)[0];
}

var all = document.all || document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0, elem; elem=all[i++];) {
    if (elem.tagName == 'IMG' && getFileName(elem.src) == 'Progress.gif') {
        elem.src = '../Images_v4/Common/Success.png';
    }
    ... THE SAME FOR THE DIVS.
}
```

It might also be a good to not go through all the elements on the page:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0, elem; elem=imgs[i++];) {
    if (getFileName(elem.src) == 'Progress.gif') {
        elem.src = '../Images_v4/Common/Success.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is document.all(i).nameProp which i use to identify the image name which is not found in all browsers but only IE....

Comment: well nameProp is IE only too, I'll wrap up some regex for you in a minute for the same functionality.